# Apache /var/www/html will read index.html, but not index.php

Tags: apache, ubuntu

ok so Im running apache on an amazon instance, I need an android app to communicate to mySQL through PHP. I can read the index.html, but my folder /var/www/android_login_api/index.php gets a 404. How can this be when it can read root folder of apache web service?

The requested URL /var/www/html/android_login_api/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Do not spam with tags that are not directly relevant for the question. I removed them now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permission  issue.  Try changing the index.php permission to 755

```
Sudo chmod 755 index.php
```

This will make the index.php file readable.
Another thought is since the android_login_api will probably have links within itself you can also use

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/android_login_api 755 -R
```

This will recursively make all your files readable

Comment: It says "chmod: invalid mode: "/var/www/html/android_login_api/index.php" :(

Comment: Sorry.  Try sudo chmod 755 index.php

Comment: @NicklasN I hate chmod syntax.  I always get jumbled.  Did my last comment work?

Comment: No :/ The command worked now, but... The requested URL /var/www/html/android_login_api/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Try chmod 755 on the folder.  Maybe we've granted read permissions inside a folder that's read protected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a **`.htaccess`** file in your **`/var/www/html`**.

And just add this line :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```